# python - blueprint declaration run with exceptions as I navigate it from a browser

Tags: python, jinja2, blueprint

I am using python 3.9.6 with ninja2 and blueprint.

```
py --version
```

returns:

> Python 3.9.6

As far as I know, blueprint is a seperate folder, with seperate html templates and static files (css/js) , and I can have many blueprints in one runnable python project.

I have looked at [Views with Jinja2 and blueprint](https://flask-diamond.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer/writing_views_with_jinja_and_blueprints/)

The hierarchy of the html+relevant files of `myblueprint` is:

> main_project -> myblueprint -> templates -> myblueprint.html
> -> static    -> myblueprint.css
> -> myblueprint.js

The relevant code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, redirect, request, render_template, url_for, session
main_page = Blueprint('myblueprint', __name__)


@main_page.route("/myblueprint")
def home():
    query = 'select * from users;'
    users = interact_db(query=query, query_type='fetch')
    return render_template('myblueprint.html')
    
...
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    return redirect("myblueprint")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #   Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.secret_key = '12345'
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

For some reason, when I run: https://localhost:5000, I get an error:

> ERROR in app: Exception on /myblueprint [GET] Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 2073, in wsgi_app
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py",
> line 1502, in dispatch_request
> return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
> File "C:/main_project/myproject/app.py", line 17, in home
> return render_template('myblueprint.html')   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py",
> line 148, in render_template
> ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),   File
> "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py",
> line 1068, in get_or_select_template
> return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)   File
> "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py",
> line 997, in get_template
> return self._load_template(name, globals)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py",
> line 958, in _load_template
> template = self.loader.load(self, name, self.make_globals(globals))   File
> "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\loaders.py",
> line 125, in load
> source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)   File
> "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py",
> line 59, in get_source
> return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)   File "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py",
> line 95, in _get_source_fast
> raise TemplateNotFound(template) jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: myblueprint.html
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2022 08:04:31] "GET /myblueprint HTTP/1.1" 500 -
> 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jan/2022 08:04:31] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -

I have also noticed that on the chrome network console (not in code run window), I see another exception:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:5000/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:5000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

What is the cross origin for blueprint, and how can I avoid that?

What is wrong in my code above, and should I fix the heirarchy?

Comment: Your `templates` folder needs to be in `C:/main_project/myproject/`

Comment: Alternatively you can try adding `template_folder="../myblueprint/templates"` to `app = Flask(...)`

Comment: It didn't succeed for template folder:
template_folder= ...
for templates it works without blueprint, but indeed, I want to use blueprint.

Comment: I changed my post. Now I see another exception (maybe for python 3.9?) - strict-origin-when-cross-origin. Should I do some extra code (and is that in new versions of python and flask?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems in your code. First you have to register your blueprint

```
import os
from flask import Flask, Blueprint, redirect, request, render_template, url_for, session

app = Flask(__name__)
main_page = Blueprint('myblueprint', __name__)


@main_page.route('/myblueprint', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    query = 'select * from users;'
    users = interact_db(query=query, query_type='fetch')
    return render_template('myblueprint.html')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    return redirect("myblueprint")


app.register_blueprint(main_page)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #   Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5800))
    app.secret_key = '12345'
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Then your html file must simply be in the templates folder:

```
> templates > myblueprint.html
```